# Drupal Form API - Using foreach loops to build forms

Tags: php, drupal, foreach, drupal-fapi

I'm building a Drupal module to tie an icon to a particular page using an administration form. Each image placed within a certain directory needs to be output with a select box next to it showing all the primary link titles.

I've built the form using a `foreach` loop but when I check the output using `dpm($form);` in the _submit function the #value for each images page element is always equal to what ever is set for the last image.

Here's my code:

```
function titleicon_admin_settings() {


  $settings = variable_get('titleicon_settings', $default);

  //build an array of primary link titles
  $primary_links_items = menu_primary_links();
  foreach ($primary_links_items as $item) {
    $title = $item['attributes']['title'];
    $href = $item['href'];
    $titles[$href] = $title;
  }

  //build array of icons
  $directory = file_directory_path() . '/icons';
  $mask = '(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG)';
  $icons = file_scan_directory($directory, $mask);



  foreach ($icons as $icon) {
    $name = $icon->name;
    $path = base_path() . $icon->filename;
    $html = '<img src="' . $path . '" width="50" height="50" />';
    $default_value = $settings[$name]['page'];

    $form[$name] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $name,
    );

    $form[$name]['path_to_icon'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => $path, 
    );

    $form[$name]['icon'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#value' => $html, 
    );

    $form[$name]['page'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Show icon on page'),
      '#default_value' => $default_value,
      '#description' => t('Choose which page to show icon on.'),
      '#options' => $titles,
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Save'), 
    );

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which makes perfect sense. If your fields are declared like this:

```
$form[$name]['path_to_icon'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $path, 
);
```

then for each file you are updating the same variable - 'path_to_icon'. Fieldset key "$name" does not matter here, as it is used only for grouping form fields together.

You would need to use something more like:

```
$form[$name]['path_to_icon_'.$name] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $path, 
);
```

then you will get multiple values after posting the form.

However, to tell the truth, I wouldn't use $name as element of variable name, you should rather have something like auto-incrementing $fid (file id from files table) or any other unique and SAFE identifier for each file...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I've got it working straight away now! Point taken on the naming of `$name` - I think there are a few areas that could be improved/made more Drupalish!

Answer (score 2):

I must say that if you put "**#tree => TRUE**" in the declaration of your fieldset :

```
$form[$name] = array(
   '#type' => 'fieldset',
   '#title' => $name,
   '#tree' => TRUE
);
```

you don't have to put "_'.$name" in all your form elements. Drupal will group all the form results in arrays keyed by $name.